# dreamweaver regular expression

Tags: dreamweaver

I have the canonical line in a huge pages as below

```
<link rel="canonical" href="10-effective-ways-to-reduce-merchant-cash-advance-business-costs.php" />
```

sure every page has it's own url, I want to search this line for all the pages and change .php to be .html

I hope if you can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution find

```
<link rel="canonical"([^<]*).php
```

replace with

```
<link rel="canonical"$1.html
```